# What is the difference between browserify external vs. exclude?

Tags: node.js, browserify

I'm using `browserify` and trying to get it to skip wasting time including or parsing jquery and other `require`-less files I've loaded via CDN.

Should I use `bundle.exclude('jquery')` or `bundle.external('jquery')`?  What is the difference?  Their output seemed identical, and the docs are unclear to me:

- `b.external`: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#bexternalfile

> Prevent file from being loaded into the current bundle, instead
>   referencing from another bundle.
>
> If file is an array, each item in file will be externalized.
>
> If file is another bundle, that bundle's contents will be read and
>   excluded from the current bundle as the bundle in file gets bundled.

- `b.exclude`: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#bexcludefile

> Prevent the module name or file at file from showing up in the output
>   bundle.
>
> If your code tries to require() that file it will throw unless you've
>   provided another mechanism for loading it.

Comment: I totally agree it's confusing. At some point I wanted to figure out exactly what the difference is and document it. I think perhaps one difference may be that `external()` can take another instance as input.

Comment: Have you found an answer for this Scott? I also find it confusing. My output seem to differ a little with exclude referencing `undefined` and external the string I put after the `--exclude` flag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Answer:

You should use `exclude`.

### Explanation:

Both functions prevent the file from being included in the bundle. For your use case, you're probably not going to `require` jQuery, so it really doesn't matter which you use. However, this is what's going on:

browserify uses [module-deps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-deps) to explore your code and find any `require` statements, and then tells module-deps where to find the required module.

If the file is in the bundle, it simply needs to provide the key for it in the bundle's module map.

If you said the file is `external`, the browserify assumes you mean it's included in another bundle, and so provides a path to the file assuming that that as an id will resolve from anther bundle. There is a little additional bookkeeping involved to be able to do this.

If you `exclude` the file, then browserify will provide `undefined` to module-deps and there will definitely be a fire when you try to use the bundle that requiring said file. However, this approach lacks the overhead of tracking the file path (which would really be negligible) and doesn't "waste time" looking in other bundles before exploding.

**Some examples:**
I fiddled with node-browserify/example/api to produce some bundles and the examples below are the module maps from various tests, somewhat formatted for readability.

Vanilla - ran as it is in the browserify repo:

```
{
    1: [function(require, module, exports) {
        module.exports = function(n) {
            return n * 3 };

    }, {}],
    2: [function(require, module, exports) {
        var bar = require('./bar');

        module.exports = function(n) {
            return n * bar(n);
        };

    }, { "./bar": 1 }],
    3: [function(require, module, exports) {
        var foo = require('./foo');
        console.log(foo(5));

    }, { "./foo": 2 }]
}
```

*`3` (main.js) depends on `./foo` which is at `2`*

*`2` (foo.js) depends on `./bar` which is at `1`*

*`1` (bar.js) has no dependencies*

Marked `api/bar.js` as external:

```
{
    1: [function(require, module, exports) {
        var bar = require('./bar');

        module.exports = function(n) {
            return n * bar(n);
        };

    }, { "./bar": "/browser/bar.js" }],
    2: [function(require, module, exports) {
        var foo = require('./foo');
        console.log(foo(5));

    }, { "./foo": 1 }]
}
```

*`2` (main.js) depends on `./foo` which is at `1`*

*`1` (foo.js) depends on `./bar` which should be labelled `/browser/bar.js` in some other bundle*

Marked `api/bar.js` to exclude:

```
{
    1: [function(require, module, exports) {
        var bar = require('./bar');

        module.exports = function(n) {
            return n * bar(n);
        };

    }, { "./bar": undefined }],
    2: [function(require, module, exports) {
        var foo = require('./foo');
        console.log(foo(5));

    }, { "./foo": 1 }]
}
```

*`2` (main.js) depends on `./foo` which is at `1`*

*`1` (foo.js) depends on `./bar` which is at ZOMFG! I dunno where it is. yru require??!1!*

Removed the exclude/external call, and removed the require of `./bar` from `foo.js`:

```
{
    1: [function(require, module, exports) {
        module.exports = function(n) {
            return n * bar(n);
        };

    }, {}],
    2: [function(require, module, exports) {
        var foo = require('./foo');
        console.log(foo(5));

    }, { "./foo": 1 }]
}
```

*`2` (main.js) depends on `./foo` which is at `1`*

*`1` (foo.js) has no dependencies, the world is peachy. I wonder if they loaded `bar` by some other means*

Answer (score 0):

The first part of @Will's answer is important too:

> For your use case, you're probably not going to require jQuery, so it really  doesn't matter which you use

I think the OP's example is confusing to ask the difference between exclude and external. If jQuery is never require()-ed in the code, then there is no questions asked: it will never be parsed by browserify and has to be loaded by other means anyway.

Just wanted to point that out as I found this confusing too.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. Presumably, OP _is_ `require()`ing jQuery in their code, but when they run it in a browser, they want their code to use the jQuery loaded from a CDN via `<script>` instead of bundling the whole jQuery package into their bundle. I too would like to know how to address that situation and I don't think Will's answer really addresses it.